# AngularJS - Are ng directives set up the same way as custom directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In reading about the `compile` and `link` functions for custom directives, I've surmised that it's during these hooks where changes can be made during template creation (compile) and hooking up scope and any transcluded elements (post-link and pre-link). Is this the way that the predefined angularJS directives behave as well (e.g. `ng-repeat`, `ng-hide`)?

For example, when an `ng-repeat` directive is found on an element: there is a compile function that would then be instructed to repeat that specified element. Then in the link function, any setup is made before the scope is attached to the templates of each of the repeated elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the core AngularJS are coded the same way that one codes custom directives.

If you wish, you can look at their source code.

The `ng-repeat` directive is one of the most complicated. It uses

```
restrict: 'A',
multiElement: true,
transclude: 'element',
priority: 1000,
terminal: true,
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `ng-repeat` Directive Source Code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L433)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)